# Whether to say "n’ont beau être que" or "ont beau n'être que"?

Tags: grammaire

> Nos chers amis australiens **n’ont beau être que** 22 millions, ils n’en possèdent pas moins l’un des pays les plus grands au monde.
>
> {or}: Nos chers amis australiens **ont beau n'être que** 22 millions, ils n’en possèdent pas moins l’un des pays les plus grands au monde.

Normally, you place "ne" immediately after the subject (of course!), but given the rather unique nature of the expression "avoir beau + infinitif", I cannot dismiss the possibility of saying "ont beau n'être que".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*N'ont beau être que* will be understood but is incorrect. *Avoir beau* is always affirmative so in your case the negative must apply to the infinitive that follows:

> *Nos chers amis australiens **ont beau n'être que** 22 millions...*

Source: [LA GRAMMAIRE DU FRANÇAIS LANGUE ÉTRANGÈRE POUR ÉTUDIANTS FINNOPHONES](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/736.html).

Comment: I would keep all *ne pas/ne que* expressions: C(2), I(1) and I(3). The *ne pas/que* ones sound relaxed spoken French to me.

Comment: @jlliagre According to the examples in the source, one should say « **ont beau ne pas être que** ». Can **pas** really be left out?

Comment: @mlj Using *pas* would reverse the meaning. *On beau n'être que 22 millions* = "despite being only 22 M" while *ont beau ne pas être que 22 millions* = "despite not being only 22 M".

Comment: "ont beau ***ne pas*** être ***que*** 22 millions" If I hear this, I (sort of automatically) interpret it as "be ***more than***  22 millions, granted" or even  "be ***way more than*** 22 millions, granted". What do you think?

Comment: “Be more than" would be the usal interpretation but the form is ambiguous.